# MySQL workbench: Copy of table column to destination column appends data at the BOTTOM of destination column not top. Why?

Tags: mysql

When I copy data from one column in source table A (I only want to copy one column) to a new column in destination table B using INSERT INTO, the copied data is placed at the bottom of the destination column instead of at the top, where I want it to go.  The destination table consists of 6 columns; source table 3 cols.  I have added an "empty" column to the destination table to receive the data from the col. in the source table. I was forced to define it as a NULL column.

To illustrate:  let's say the destination table has 5 columns of 1000 rows each.  The destination column is nominally "empty" before the copying.  When I finished copying, the first 1000 rows of the destination column have been filled with NULL statements and the copied data begins with row 1001.  Now, only the new destination column holds any data after row 1000.

Deleting the NULL statements from the first 1000 rows doesn't move the copied data up to the top.  I suspect that the problem may be because the column definitions of the destination table were originally all set at NULL.  They should probably have been set at NN but I don't know if this is what is causing my problem.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying, but I think you might be confusing rows and columns. Please show sample data, the `INSERT` query, and the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in sql is organized by rows, not columns.  insert always inserts new rows, never modifies existing ones (unless you specify `on duplicate key update ...`).  It sounds like you want to update existing rows; you use the `update` statement for that, not the `insert` statement, and you have to provide information to identify which rows to update.